# Angular FormGroup .get() can be null

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

Whenever I do `this.formGroup.get('control name')`, it says that the control may return null, so Typescript says to add a `?` before any method/attribute calls from this control.

I've worked a lot with an older version of Angular, and this did not happened at that time. Is this some new feature of Angular or perhaps TS?

I would like to know if there is a way to ensure that the return of `.get()` will not be null?

It is a good thing to have, so I would not like to have it disabled, only a way to handle it.

Example:

```js
const formGroup = this.formBuilder
.group({ control: [{ name: [{ value: null, disabled: false }] }] });


const control = formGroup.get('name');

// I am asked to add `?`, since `control` can be null
const value = control?.value;
```

I've tried to add a null validator, in a if-statement/ternary-if, but it did amount to anything, still am asked to add the ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually how you do this is by using one of these two approaches:

1. Use the NonNullable version of a FormBuilder:

```
const formGroup = this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
  name: [{ value: 'abc', disabled: false }],
});
```

2. Use the `{ nonNullable: true }` option for each FormControl inside the group:

```
const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [{ value: 'abc', disabled: false }, { nonNullable: true }],
});
```

Either way will work just fine.

---

However the problem that you're seeing in your example won't be fixed by this unfortunately. And that's because currently the `.get()` method adds a `| null` to the result, even for a nonNullable fromGroup/formControl.

The only way to avoid it for now, is to use the `.controls[ctrl_name]` instead. This will allow you to avoid adding the `?.` operator:

```
const formGroup = this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
  name: [{ value: 'abc', disabled: false }],
});

const control = formGroup.controls['name'];

// you don't need to a addd "?." anymore
const value = control.value;
```

I hope that this helps!

Comment: The reason why .get() might return a null is because it is possible for one to do something like .get(<non existent attribute>.  

Setting the nonNullable at group or control level, is just to indicate that the control(s)' values are NOT nullable.  

In other word, setting nonNullable and get() are 2 different things. Do correct me, if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @NickWills I think your explanation is pretty spot on. However this distinction between the two is still counterintuitive and confusing for many.

Comment: Agree. The distinction is indeed counterintuitive and confusing.  Hopefully documentation would highlight this.  Side note:  i just done an experiment and discover nonNullable at group level does not imply each control in the grp is automatically {nonNullable: true}.  I not sure why also.  Still investigating.

Comment: Ignore what i say regarding my side note. I realize that if we use nonNullable.group,   when we define control by writing "new FormControl(...)",  the nonNullable (define at group level) will NOT flow down to the control.